# why isn't my bash prompt properly escaping?

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I have the following bash prompt variable, defined in my .basrhc file:

`PS1='\u@\h:\[\e[01;34m\] \[$(pwd|sed -e "s!.*/\\([^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\\)!\\1!g")\] \[\e[00m\] \[\e[01;31m\]\t\[\e[00m\]\$ '`

From a directory, /one/two/three/four/, this would look like a colourised version of:

`me@my-computer two/three/four 12:01:37$`

(I wan't to put an image of what I get, but I'm a newcomer with no rep points..)

I'm having problems with it not being escaped properly (I think this is the source) in that, when scrolling up through my history, the lines truncate the bash prompt, and the terminal doesn't display the cursor in the correct place of the command line.  You may have to scroll up a fair few lines before this effect is seen though.

I think the problem is the `sed` command but I'm not sure how to resolve it if that's right.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to set the value of `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` instead. It works slightly differently from what you want, but it's probably close enough, it's built-in to `bash`, and it's a lot easier to use. (Note: `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` is new to `bash` 4.x (at least 4.1, possibly 4.0)).

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
PS1='\u@\h:\[\e[01;34m\] \w\[\e[00m\] \[\e[01;31m\]\t\[\e[00m\]\$ '
```

You can also make use of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable to simply creating your prompt by breaking it into manageable steps. This will work in earlier versions of `bash`, if `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` isn't available or isn't to your liking.

```
prompt_cmd () {
    # Trim leading directories off the current working directory.
    # Use single quotes so you don't need to escape the backslashes.
    trimmed_pwd=$( pwd | sed -e 's!.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*\)!\1!g' )

    # The initial part of your prompt
    PS1='\u@\h:\[\e[01;34m\] '
    # Add the directory; no single quotes, so the parameter expands, and
    # no need to wrap it in \[ \]
    PS1+=$trimmed_pwd
    # And the final part of your prompt
    PS1+='\[\e[00m\] \[\e[1;31m\]\t\[\e[00m\]\$ '
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_cmd'
```

Comment: I'm on Bash 4.1 and your `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3` solution seems to work well, except that it introduces 3 full stops and a slash when it trims the higher directories, giving: `me@my-computer two/three/four 12:01:37$`.  Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Also, I think your final colour escape in your second solution is missing an 'm' so the produced text is coloured the same as the time. Great answer though, thanks!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; that's what I (obliquely) referred to when I said it worked differently. If you don't like the `...`, I would try the `PROMPT_COMMAND` approach to your original code. I'll fix the escape code issue :)

Comment: Ok, second solution it is.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think there's one extra backslash in that final colour escape as well.  I tried to edit it, but I need to change at least 6 characters..

Answer (score 0):

In the sed command single quotes and a bit simple regex seems to work. Prompt and color stuff is unknown to me, hope this helps.

```
sed 's!..*/\(.*/.*/.*\)!\1!g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the regex.  I originally had single quotes but it seemed like the whole `PS1` variable needed single quoting, so I didn't think I could nest them.  If they're contained in `$(...)` does that mean they're not nested?